# How to handle webexception in wpf Frame control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I'm using Frame control to display the webpage in wpf app but it throws **WebException(Can't locate the remote server)** if there is no internet connection.
How can I handle the WebException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the Frame control actually hosts an ActiveX control for the web browsing.  When you set the *Source* property or call the *Navigate* method, it will asynchonously attempt to navigate the URI.

According to [this MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/57b1f8f0-33c4-41c4-8a2d-4d64cebdb9b3/wrong-uri-for-frame-makes-wpf-application-to-crash), you'll need to register to handle this asynchronous exception on the **Dispatcher.UnhandledException** event.